# Load PostgreSQL database to SchemaRDD

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have data source in PostgreSQL with 1 Million rows and 100+ columns, and I want to use Spark SQL so I want to transform this data source to get `SchemaRDD`.

Two approaches are introduced in [Spark SQL Programming Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html),
 one is through reflection, which means I need to define:

```
case class Row(Var1: Int, Var2: String, ...)
```

This is tedious because I have 100+ columns.

Another approach is "Programmatically Specifying the Schema", which means I need to define:

```
val schema =
  StructType(
    Seq(StructField("Var1", IntegerType), StructField("Var2", StringType), ...))
```

This is also tedious for me.

Actually, there's still another problem because I load my `PostgreSQL` database using `JdbcRDD` class but I found I also need to define the schema in the `mapRow` parameter of `JdbcRDD` constructor, which looks like:

```
def extractValues(r: ResultSet) = {
  (r.getInt("Var1"), r.getString("Var2"), ...)
}
val dbRDD = new JdbcRDD(sc, createConnection,
  "SELECT * FROM PostgreSQL OFFSET ? LIMIT ?",
  0, 1000000, 1, extractValues)
```

This API still asks me to create the schema by myself, what's worse is that I need to redo the similar thing to transform this `JdbcRDD` to `SchemaRDD`, that would be really clumsy code.

So I want to know what's the best approach for this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only a limited number of data types that you need to support.  Why not use the

```
java.sql.ResultSetMetaData
```

e.g.

```
val rs = jdbcStatement.executeQuery("select * from myTable limit 1")
val rmeta = rs.getMetaData
```

to read one row and then dynamically generate the required  StructField  for each of the columns.

You would need a case statement to handle

```
val myStructFields = for (cx <- 0 until rmeta.getColumnCount) {
       val jdbcType = rmeta.getColumnType(cx)
       } yield StructField(rmeta.getColumnName(cx),jdbcToSparkType(jdbcType))

val mySchema = StructType(myStructFields.toSeq)
```

Where jdbcToSparkType is along the following lines:

```
  def jdbcToSparkType(jdbcType: Int) = {
    jdbcType match {
       case 4 => InteegerType  
       case 6 => FloatType
        ..
   }
```

**UPDATE**  To generate the RDD[Row] : you would follow a similar pattern.  In this case you would

```
val rows = for (rs.next) {
    row = jdbcToSpark(rs)
    } yield row

val rowRDD = sc.parallelize(rows)
```

where

```
def jdbcToSpark(rs: ResultSet) = {
   var rowSeq = Seq[Any]()
   for (cx <- 0 to rs.getMetaData.getColumnCount) {
     rs.getColumnType(cx) match {
         case 4 => rowSeq :+ rs.getInt(cx)
          ..
     }
   }
   Row.fromSeq(rowSeq)
}
```

then
    val rows